# Share OneDrive folder to specific Microsoft accounts

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Is it possible to share a folder on OneDrive only to some specific people (= specific Microsoft accounts)?

So far I have only found an option to share to "anyone who has the link"...

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer I will make it accepted.

Comment: @Ramhound You can access sharing options for OneDrive folders from Windows directIy... I don't want to argue with you, but your opinion on being off topic seems quite strict to me in this case...

Comment: Alright; Sure I will concede that point then.